# Removed GNOME desktop, cannot connect to internet from terminal

Tags: networking, fedora, gnome, package-management

I'm using Fedora 19. I removed my GNOME-Desktop (`sudo yum remove @gnome-desktop`). After that when I try to connect to internet from command line i'm facing all sorts of issues..

Ethernet cable is also connected however when i execute

```
$ ping www.google.com
```

returns

```
connect: Network is unreachable
```

When I try to execute commands like `wifi-menu` or `netctl`, i'm getting error that

```
$ bash: command not found
```

Any idea on how to resolve this...

Answer (score 3):

You've accidentally removed `NetworkManager` during the uninstall of GNOME Desktop.

Reinstall it with:

```
sudo yum install NetworkManager
```

and restart the Network Manager service:

```
sudo systemctl start NetworkManager.service
```

Check that you are connected with:

```
nmcli d
```

which will hopefully show something similar to:

```
DEVICE     TYPE              STATE        
eth0       802-3-ethernet    connected
```

Note - the device might not be named `eth0` in your setup.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to installing NetworkManager would be to configure the interface manually. On Fedora, you'll have to look at `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-<iface_name>`

Replace `<iface_name>` with the actual name of the interface you're trying to configure.

Edit that file to specify whether that interface will be configured via DHCP or manually. In the latter case, you'll also have to provide an IP address, a subnet mask and the IP address of the default gateway.

Assuming your interface is called `eth0`, the following configuration in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` should help you obtain an IP from DHCP:

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=DHCP
ONBOOT=yes
```

See the [Fedora docs](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-networkscripts-interfaces.html) for more information.

After the configuration file is in place, you need to issue

```
ifconfig eth0 up
```

or

```
ifup eth0
```